# Tile Grout: Patch up gaps, or strip out grout and regrout the whole thing?

Tags: shower, tile, grout

I have tiled walls around a built in enameled tub. The tile itself (4x4) is in excellent condition. However, there are a lot of gaps in the grout, from half an inch to two inches in length, scattered around.

The tile job was done about 16 years ago.

I like the tile and want to keep it. (It is pretty.)

Should I strip out all the grout and regrout the whole thing? Or is it OK to just push some grout into the gaps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could push some grout into the bare areas but even if it was original from the same bag it will now be a different shade. I usually strip the grout for a level but not the entire wall I might cut just a slight amount on everything and when filling the bare areas work everything so the color matches or is not as obvious. After 16 years I probably would not be looking for flexing in this case and a refill will probably be fine.

Comment: How best to remove the existing grout?

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica   You can get a tile grout saw at your home store.They're about  5 to 10 bucks.  Get a dust mask too.+

Comment: I prefer a saw , some use dremel tools but 1 slip and there is a scar on the tile, the saw is slower but you don’t need to cut much out and grout is soft.